# Make PyQt resources available to other Python classes

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am developing a GUI with PyQt, and I'd like to use the PyQt resource system to keep track of my resources (images, templates, etc). I'm trying to find a way that I can get the absolute path to my resources so that I can load them with non-PyQt classes. For instance, I would like to be able to get the path to a resource image and plot it with matplotlib, e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from PyQt5 import QMysteryClass

qimg = QMysteryClass(":/myresource.png")
img = mpimg.imread( qimg.absolutePath() )
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow( img )
plt.show()
```

Does anyone know if the PyQt resource system supports this kind of use, or will I just have to manage my resources some other way?

Answer (score 1):

You should read [this doc](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/resources.html) about the Qt resource system. Basically you construct a .qrc XML file and use pyrcc5 executable to convert that into a python module you can import.

Once you have your python module you can do stuff like `QFile(":/path/to/file")` for reading the contents, or use `QImage` directly since you want to work with images. Additionally, notice that your files are in memory so you can't access them in non-Qt classes with a path, which is why you need to read the data from memory instead. Load your image data into a buffer and read it into your matplotlib classes.

From the [matplotlib.image.imread](http://fossies.org/dox/matplotlib-1.4.3/namespacematplotlib_1_1image.html#aa1eebdb78e57244559dcf6b8fd62ad28) doc:

> *fname* may be a string path or a Python file-like object.  If
>   using a file object, it must be opened in binary mode.

Therefore you should be able to wrap your data in a [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=bytesio#io.BytesIO) object.

Comment: Ironically, the example you linked to describes how to include resources *without* using pyrcc.